# How to explicitly instruct PyTest to drop a database after some tests?

Tags: python, django, database, pytest, pytest-django

I am writing unit-tests with pytest-django for a django app. I want to make my tests more performant and doing so is requiring me to keep data saved in database for a certain time and not drop it after one test only. For example:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_save():
    p1 = MyModel.objects.create(description="some description") # this object has the id 1
    p1.save()

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_modify():
    p1 = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
    p1.description = "new description"
```

What I want is to know how to keep both tests separated but both will use the same test database for some time and drop it thereafter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need are pytest fixtures. They allow you yo create objects (stored in database if needed) that will be used during tests. You can have a look at pytest fixtures scope that you can set so that the fixture is not deleted from database and reloading for each test that requires it but instead is created once for a bunch of tests and deleted afterwards.

You should read the documentation of pytest fixtures (https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html) and the section dedicated to fixtures' scope (https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session).

Comment: Thank you, I've saw your documentation and it surely does what I want it too. But it doesn't seem to work in pytest-django as the error ```ValueError: class fixtures not supported (maybe in the future)``` is raised. But I found a way to reduce time by adding on ```addopts = --reuse-db``` on pytest.ini file, data is not saved but we don't have to create a database on each test.

Comment: Actually you may be right with the `class` scope. All other (`function` and `session`) should be available though. I suggest you use the `session` scope in addition to the `--reuse-db` if needed.

Comment: Make sure you installed `pytest-django` though.